# .NET 5 SOAP WCF service ssl error client certificate

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I try to connect to a SOAP service with the .NET 5 WCF-Framework and I've a problem with the client certificate. The client certificate is a "self-signed" generated (from SOAP-Service provider) ssl certificate. If I install the certificate on the windows keychain everything works fine, but I can't install the certificate on the production system, because the same certificate is used by many other customers. I think it's untrust if the windows trust a self-signed certificate (many users know the private key).

If the cert is not in the windows keychain the code throw this exception:

```
CommunicationException: An error occurred while sending the request.
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
WinHttpException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority
```

Is theire any way to trust the certificate in .net? (ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback not works)

```
BasicHttpsBinding bb = new BasicHttpsBinding();
bb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
SoapService x = new SoapService(bb, new EndpointAddress("[address]"));
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), [password]);
x.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificate;
```

Thank You!

Comment: Why can't you use the production certificate?  Can you give the certificate a different name?

Comment: I get one certificate from the SOAP-Service provider. This certificate is using by many different companys. If i install this certificate in the production windows keystore, many different companys know the private key of the root cert. They can generate other certificates with the private key.

Comment: The certificate is stored with admin privilege in the machine stores and is the user user stores.  So how can other companies be able to read the certificate?

Comment: The SOAP-Service-provider-company send to the companys the same certificate. Its not individual. Many companys use the same certificate.

Comment: If it is the same certificate then what is the issue?  the key can only be read by an admin and the user.  Other users cannot read the certificate.

Comment: yes in my Company admins and users (thats not the problem). But in many other companys (the other companys have the same cert) can also all users read the private key. (the private key is Not secret). If the computers in my company Trust this root cert it‘s unsecure

Comment: Then create a different certificate for each company with a different name. SSL has a certificate block which the server sends to a client that has a list of certificate names.  Then the client looks up the certificate by name to get key.  Only one certificate name has to match.  You cannot keep a key private if you send it to lots of companies.

Comment: I cant change the client certificate, because the server only accept this certificate. Is there no way to allow .net using this certificate without adding the cert to Windows keystore?

Comment: The certificate is authenticated using TLS and you would have to write your own TLS layer.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-5.0

Comment: Is there no easier way to say .net trusting this cert for the Soap Request?

Comment: The TLS is done before the HTTP request when you are using HTTPS (secure).   The TLS as part of the authentication the server sends a certificate block to the client with a list of certificate names.  Then the names are lookup in the user certificate stores to get the private key.  The private key is not transmitted between client/server.  You have a poor design if you are using the same private key with different companies.  Each company should have its own private key.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem. But I'm not responsible for the SOAP server. The soap service provider sent me a certificate that is used by many companys for first verification on the soap server. But the certificate is not unique for each company! Thats the reason because I dont want saving the cert in the windows keychain. I sent the client certificate with this command to the server 
x.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificate;
Is there no way to say .net that .net should trust this certificate? The server certificate is a offical certificate.

Comment: What about using a proxy server?